# How can we configure google cloud deployment template for DNS mapping with Cloud DNS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have deployment template, jinja+yaml files to create and VM instance and attach a static IP. And it works great.

I'd like to do the DNS mapping within the template as well because I have DNS zone and I just got static IP.

I found this document about resource Type"dns.v1.managedZone" but it seems only for creating a new zone itself but not the create subdomain/A record mapping under it.

https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types

Hope someone knows anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

To create entries in your DNS server, you need to use `Resource Records`. These are children to a DNS Zone.

Here is a link to the Google documentation:

[ResourceRecordSets](https://cloud.google.com/dns/api/v1/resourceRecordSets)